# can we convert docx file into PDF using javascript without js libraries

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I want to create LWC component in which I have one file selector which is uploading '.pdf', '.png','.jpg','.jpeg','.docx','.doc' types of file in salesforce. but on button click I want that file to get converted into PDF and gets download immediately.
Is it possible to convert file using js in LWC?.

I got this code but it is only working on string containing HTML element. I want it to work on whole file.

```
window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
var doc = new jsPDF();
    
// Source HTMLElement or a string containing HTML.
var elementHTML = document.querySelector("#content");

doc.html(elementHTML, {
    callback: function(doc) {
        // Save the PDF
        doc.save('sample-document.pdf');
    },
    margin: [10, 10, 10, 10],
    autoPaging: 'text',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 190, //target width in the PDF document
    windowWidth: 675 //window width in CSS pixels
});
```

Comment: thanks, please suggest some js libraries for conversion

Comment: If you do not wish to include a JS library with your component, one way to do this is through using an externally hosted Cloud Service to perform the conversion. The [LEADTOOLS Hosted Cloud Services](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/products/hosted-services) has the [Convert](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/cloud-services/convert.html) API which can be used to convert DOCX to PDF. If you are interested, you can find a demo for this [here](https://services.leadtools.com/demo). (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)